# Who is setting the content-type response header for an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, content-type, response-headers

I have an ASP.NET WebForms application which displays chinese characters. The characters are not html encoded. The content-type of the html file is set to iso-8859-1 encoding but the content-type response header is set to utf-8 as you can see in the following screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to find out who is setting the response header to utf-8. I couldn't find it in the code and it is also not configured in IIS.

Does anyone know how we can set it in code or if utf-8 is the default? If it was the default, why would it be not overriden by iso-8859-1 then?

I'm clueless at the moment.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-http-response-headers is this what you want?

Comment: Check your web.config, maybe you have something like this: <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-gb" uiCulture="en"/> If so, edit attributes with ecoding.